# VB.NET control form from module

Tags: vb.net

I recently have convert my project from VB6 to VB.NET2008,
after the convert here is a sub that control form from a module that i create,
the error was something like

> "cmdAdd is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Form"

```
Public Sub ButtonSet(ByRef frmObj As System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    frmObj.cmdAdd.Visible = True
    frmObj.cmdCopy.Visible = True
    frmObj.cmdEdit.Visible = True
    frmObj.cmdCorrection.Visible = True
End Sub
```

how its call:

```
Private Sub frmAPNote_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
ButtonSet(Me)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parameter type to `YourFormName`.

```
Public Sub ButtonSet(ByRef frmObj As frmAPNote)
    frmObj.cmdAdd.Visible = True
    frmObj.cmdCopy.Visible = True
    frmObj.cmdEdit.Visible = True
    frmObj.cmdCorrection.Visible = True
End Sub
```

PS: No need to specify ByRef parameter type for objects.

> The problem is the sub in the module not only just called by "frmAPNote" but also other form such as "frmARNote" and "frmRTNote"

You may get the reference of a specific control from `Form.Controls` collection.

```
Public Sub ButtonSet(ByVal frmObj As Form)
    Dim btnAdd = frmObj.Controls("btnAdd")

    If Not IsNothing(btnAdd) Then
        btnAdd.Visible = False
    End If

    ....
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is the sub in the module not only just called by "frmAPNote" but also other form such as "frmARNote" and "frmRTNote".

Comment: @monaz g: Then make a base class or interface that they all use, then use that as the type.

Comment: Hi jmoreno, that is what i'm trying to do with this sub, can you give example how to do it by using "base class or interface"?